# AngularJS : check if a model value has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

IS there a way to check a dirty flag on the model itself, independent of the view?

I need the angular controller to know what properties have been changed, in order to only save changed variables to server.

I have implemented logic regarding if my entire form is dirty or pristine, but that is not specific enough

I could just slap a name and ng-form attribute on every input, to make it recognizable as a form in the controller, but then I end up with a controller that is strongly coupled with the view.

Another not-so appealing approach is to store the initial values that every input is bound to in a separate object, then compare the current values with the initial values to know if they have changed.

I checked [Monitor specific fields for pristine/dirty form state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702124/monitor-specific-fields-for-pristine-dirty-form-state) and [AngularJS : $pristine for ng-check checked inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620660/angularjs-pristine-for-ng-check-checked-inputs)

Comment: You mean, like, with $watchers? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch
Maybe I'm missing something more specific. Can you clarify?

Comment: watchers trigeer event with every singe change. what I am looking for is a check to perform during a save operation, detecting what values have changed in order to send only these to the server. its essential yhr same as $pristine, but without needing a separate form for every variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I could think of is

1. As you get a model/object from service, create a replica of the model within the model and bind this new model to your view.
2. Add a watch on the new Model and as the model changes, use the replica to compare old and new models as follows

   ```
   var myModel = {
       property1: "Property1",
       property2: "Property2",
       array1:["1","2","3"]
   }
   var getModel = function(myModel){
      var oldData = {};
      for(var prop in myModel){
         oldData.prop = myModel[prop];
      }
      myModel.oldData = oldData;
      return myModel;
   }
   var getPropChanged = function(myModel){
     var oldData = myModel.oldData;
     for(var prop in myModel){
      if(prop !== "oldData"){
       if(myModel[prop] !== oldData[prop]){
           return{
               propChanged: prop,
               oldValue:oldData[prop],
               newValue:myModel[prop]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the complete code example. this is essentailly what I describe in the second option mentioned in the question. I will use this approach unless a more compellng solution is available.

Comment: Welcome Toad. Do not forget to tick the answer :)

Comment: You may want to check for hasOwnProperty(prop) to avoid an enumeration of prototype properties.

if (oldData.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
   //handle your business...
}

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easiest to store and later compare against the JSON representation of the object, rather than looping through the various properties.

See [Detect unsaved data using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849857/detect-unsaved-data-using-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

The class shown below may work well for your purpose, and is easily reused across pages.

At the time you load your models, you remember their original values:

```
    $scope.originalValues = new OriginalValues();

    // Set the model and remember it's value
    $scope.someobject = ...
    var key = 'type-' + $scope.someobject.some_unique_key;
    $scope.originalValues.remember(key, $scope.someobject);
```

Later you can determine if it needs to be saved using:

```
    var key = 'type-' + $scope.someobject.some_unique_key;
    if ($scope.originalValues.changed(key, $scope.someobject)) {
       // Save someobject
       ...
    }
```

The key allows you to remember the original values for multiple models. If you only have one ng-model the key can simply be 'model' or any other string.

The assumption is that properties starting with '$' or '_' should be ignored when looking for changes, and that new properties will not be added by the UI.

Here's the class definition:

```
function OriginalValues() {
    var hashtable = [ ]; // name -> json

    return {

      // Remember an object returned by the API
      remember: function(key, object) {
        // Create a clone, without system properties.
        var newobj = { };
        for (var property in object) {
          if (object.hasOwnProperty(property) && !property.startsWith('_') && !property.startsWith('$')) {
            newobj[property] = object[property];
          }
        }
        hashtable[key] = newobj;
      },// remember

      // See if this object matches the original
      changed: function(key, object) {
        if (!object) {
          return false; // Object does not exist
        }

        var original = hashtable[key];
        if (!original) {
          return true; // New object
        }

        // Compare against the original
        for (var property in original) {
          var changed = false;
          if (object[property] !== original[property]) {
            return true; // Property has changed
          }
        }
        return false;
      }// changed

    }; // returned object
  } // OriginalValues
```